# In mongoose I have executed the example program given in the website but I'm getting the same error that is: TypeError: fluffy.speak is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
    console.log("We are successfully connected");
}
const kittySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});
const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema);
const silence = new Kitten({ name: 'Silence' });
console.log(silence.name);
kittySchema.methods.speak = function speak() {
    const greeting = this.name
        ? "Meow name is " + this.name
        : "I don't have a name";
    console.log(greeting);
};
```

`This is not running and showing as not a function`
const fluffy = new Kitten({ name: 'fluffy' });
fluffy.speak();

Answer (score 0):

On the [Getting Started](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/#getting-started) page for mongoose, it indicates that methods must be declared before calling `mongoose.model()`:

> ````
> // NOTE: methods must be added to the schema before compiling it with mongoose.model()
> kittySchema.methods.speak = function speak() {  
>   const greeting = this.name
>     ? "Meow name is " + this.name
>     : "I don't have a name";
>   console.log(greeting);
> };
> const Kitten = mongoose.model('Kitten', kittySchema); ```
> ````